# Android: GoogleMaps on fragment LongPressClick doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to pin a new mark on my map but method onMapLongClick didn work.
My code is below. I have my map inside a fragment.

```
public class Fragment_maps extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment 
implements OnMapLongClickListener, OnMapClickListener{ 

MapView mMapView; 
private GoogleMap googleMap; 

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    // inflate and return the layout 
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, 
            false); 
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map); 
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //activate menu button
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately 

    try { 
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    //get the map
    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    // Detect location
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    // Turns traffic layer on
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    // Enables indoor maps
    googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    // Enables indoor maps
    googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    // Turns on 3D buildings
    googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    // Show Zoom buttons
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    // latitude and longitude 
    double latitude = 40.639350; 
    double longitude = 22.944607;


    // create marker 
    MarkerOptions thessaloniki = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Thessaloniki");
    //----------------
    MarkerOptions LeykosPyrgos = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.626401, 22.948352)).title("Leykos Pyrgos");

    // Changing marker icon 
    thessaloniki.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
    //----------------
    LeykosPyrgos.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.whitetower));

    // adding marker 
    googleMap.addMarker(thessaloniki); 
    CameraPosition cameraPositionThess = new CameraPosition.Builder() .target(new LatLng(40.639350, 22.944607)).zoom(12).build(); 
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory .newCameraPosition(cameraPositionThess));
    //----------------
    googleMap.addMarker(LeykosPyrgos); 
    CameraPosition cameraPositionLeykosPyrgos = new CameraPosition.Builder() .target(new LatLng(40.626401, 22.948352)).zoom(12).build(); 
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory .newCameraPosition(cameraPositionLeykosPyrgos));


    // Perform any camera updates here 
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_maps, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected","yes");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.HYBRID:
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);;
        return true;
    case R.id.SATELLITE:
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        return true;
    case R.id.TERRAIN:
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        return true;
    case R.id.NORMAL:
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),point.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
}

@Override 
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(point)
        .title("You are here")           
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));  
}

@Override 
public void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
    mMapView.onResume(); 
} 

@Override 
public void onPause() { 
    super.onPause(); 
    mMapView.onPause(); 
} 

@Override 
public void onDestroy() { 
    super.onDestroy(); 
    mMapView.onDestroy(); 
} 

@Override 
public void onLowMemory() { 
    super.onLowMemory(); 
    mMapView.onLowMemory(); 
}
```

}

As you can see I have both `onMapClick` and `onMapLongClick` methods but when I click on map nothing happens. I also have implement `OnMapLongClickListener` and `OnMapClickListener`. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class implements the listener but you don't **set** it:

```
googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
```

same with the normal click listener:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
```